# What is the effect of repeated sensor cleaning on the battery?

Tags: battery, canon-600d

I have configured my Canon EOS600D to

- auto shut-down after 3 minutes
- do a sensor cleaning when *manually*  switching off

Now I wonder what is prefereable behaviour (especially, battery-wise) when I'm doing an extended foto-stroll. That is, how does a sensor cleaning compare to 3 minutes of the camera being on and idling? Is it better to manually turn off the camera when I can foresee that the next picture will be further than 3 minutes away?

(I don't want to configure away the manual sensor cleaning or the auto-shutdown, for I might otherwise forget things like turnng off or sensor cleaing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only Canon knows for sure much current a sensor cleaning consumes, but it's going to be significantly less than what the LCD's backlight consumed while you were reviewing your last shot.

If you're turning your camera on and off lots of times during an afternoon, the sensor will be cleaned far more times than needed unless you spend a lot of time shooting in dust storms.

Most Canons draw so little when idle that a friend of mine doesn't even bother switching his bodies off before putting them away.  My advice is to disable auto power off entirely, turn the camera on, shoot for whatever length of time you need, shut it off when you're done and don't worry so much about idle vs. powered-off battery consumption.

Comment: The only thing the power button if useful for is to stop it taking photos of your feet while you walk around. :)

Comment: @alex I've even once had a facepalm moment hwne I worked in filming mode and repeatedly picked up the camera started filminng stopped filming, lowered trhe camera etc. - until after a few shots I noticed that I was "off by ine" and hence had filmed *only* my walking feet.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way I know is to set camera to sleep after some time (mine is 1 minute). In sleep mode battery consumption in negligible so during the walk/photo session i keep the camera in this mode. When I am back home after transferring photos I switch it off.

Sensor cleaning "shake" the sensor to "remove" particles/dust from it. It is not very power consuming, but it is not wise to do it every 5 minutes :)